# Why was my question closed as off topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked this simple question: [How to programatically delete or rename an Azure Active Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056715/how-to-delete-an-azure-active-directory). I did some fast internet research and found no answer to it. It is definitely not an opinion question, it's topic is a tool that programmers use every day (azure). So why did it get closed?

Comment: Because it doesn't directly relate to programming, and possibly is better for superuser or server fault (I'm not entirely sure what Azure is)?

Comment: You aren't asking how to do this programatically and I assume [sf] would in fact be a better fit. But that is not available as a migration target.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII so if you don't know what Azure is, how can you even have an opinion on my question?

Comment: @MartinSmith So it would be polite to leave a comment asking me to ask the question at ServerFault, because it can't be migrated. Closing just like that is plain rude.

Comment: While I agree the question is on topic, closing isn't rude @vainolo. It's a necessary function of the site, and - as you've found out - quite easy to reverse. Remember, you are the one asking for free help, and no one's accusing you of rudeness for posting a poorly worded question.

Comment: @Yannis closing a correct question without leaving a comment and not letting me improve the question is kind of rude. I know it is necessary but I think it is abused. Most people won't come to meta and complaint. They'll simply either go away or ask the question again differently

Comment: @vainolo Oh come on, that's more than a stretch. You're the one asking, it's your responsibility to get it right. I'm not saying it's not nice when people post comments explaining their close votes, but it's certainly not rude when they don't.

Comment: @Yannis "rude" is a feeling. I felt it. It is completely subjective. But to each his own opinions

Comment: @vainolo Ok then. _My_ feeling is that calling people that freely volunteer their time to moderate the site rude is... rude.

Comment: @Yannis Since I'm also a reviewer, and I also vote to close questions, I think I can talk freely.

Comment: Nope, its completely off topic.  Closed again.  Questions about managing virtual Active Directory instances on a cloud service are completely off topic.  ServerFault probably accepts these questions.

Comment: @Won't - I'm not quite as sure as you are. What if the console does not have this option, but the API does? It is very common that programmers have better tools, with more capabilities. (for example - SharePoint has many capabilities that most users cannot access, because the UI does not expose them). Specifically for Azure, I don't know. (by the way, it was another moderator who opened that post)

Comment: @Kobi: API calls are different.  The question doesn't discuss any API calls.  The accepted answer does not either.  If he wants to use the Azure API to configure something, that is totally on topic, as it is programming related.

Comment: @Won't Edited the question so it is now completely on topic (programmatically remove). I have also gotten some upvotes (and many views), so it seems the question is not irrelevant at all. Will this question stay closed or will it become open again sometime?

Answer (score 4):

Your question was closed because it was poorly worded: You wrote "Directory" instead of "Active Directory", and many people understood your question as too simple. It is also borderline on Server Fault.
You could have made it more obvious by capitalizing the name like astaykov did in his answer: Azure Active Directory looks better than "azure active directory".
You could have also added a blurb about "Is there a code or API solution if the console doesn't support this feature?" - that would hint the question can only be answered here.

Either way, I think your question belongs on Stack Overflow, and I voted to reopen it.

Comment: Thanks @Kobi. You are right that my question was poorly written and needed improvement.